# ASIHTTPRequest iOS call once but response many times

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, response

I got a problem with ASIHTTPRequest in my iOS project. I start a request but sometimes it response twice or more.

When I start request:

```
 [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
request.timeOutSeconds = 60;
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getListProduct_OnSuccess:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(getListProduct_OnError:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

but it run into getListProduct_OnSuccess sometimes once, but sometimes twice, or more.
Can you help me? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this ASIHTTPRequestDelegate methods,

```
// These are the default delegate methods for request status
// You can use different ones by setting didStartSelector / didFinishSelector / didFailSelector

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request; 

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

And inside these methods you can set your selector methods.

I think this may help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yoururl"];    
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:email forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:pasw forKey:@"pass"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is when I request with method GET, it run in setDidFinishSelector function many times. I think there's a property I didn't set or something like that.